# Does jest mock function jest.fn() when called with .tohavebeencalled shows trace in jest coverage??In react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

If yes! then i am not able to find the trace of it using jest --coverage where the lines of code are represented, apart from this i have done the mock function call using jest documentation and the test is passed but no trace of the function call made in coverage

i have tried jest.fn() and jest.spyOn functions and calls with shallow,render predefined functions of Enzyme

**MainPage to which call has to be made**

```
export default class AddJobOverview extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);



 <NextButton onClick = {this.handleNext} id={"nextButton"}/>
                </MainContainer>
            </div>
```

**TEST CODE**

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import AddJobOverview from '../../../Components/Modules/AddJob/AddJobOverview.jsx';
import NextButton from '../../../Components/Modules/AddJob/AddJobOverview.jsx'
import {handleNext} from '../../../Components/Modules/AddJob/AddJobOverview.jsx'
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';



describe('AddJobOverview component', () => {

    it('AddJobOverview component renders without crashing', () => {
        shallow(<AddJobOverview/>);

    });


//1st test case
    it('handlenext works Correctly', () => {
        const Fakefun=jest.spyOn(AddJobOverview.prototype,'handleNext');
        const component=shallow((<AddJobOverview/>));

        component.update();
        expect(Fakefun).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
//2nd Test case
    it('handlechange works Correctly', () => {
        const handleChange=jest.fn();
        handleChange();
        expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });


});
```

So in the above code test 1 is failing due to some jest.fn error it can be solved!!in the second test case the test is passed but shows no trace in coverage.so how to check if the test case 2 is valid if yes then how to find the trace??